# Get next data on button click

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to use some buttons to move back and forward on SQLite data. If I click on the "back" button, it works ok. But if click on next button, it goes to the last record and it messes up all data.

This is the code I'm using to move back on SQLite:

```
    query = "SELECT _id, semana_ano, ano, dia,(valor_uber||'\n('||total_valor||')') AS valores,kms,horas_uber,media_hora,media_km " +
                        "FROM uber_records WHERE semana_ano < '"+dias_semana+"' GROUP BY semana_ano ORDER BY dia";
                cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
```

And this to move to next:

```
    query = "SELECT _id, semana_ano, ano, dia,(valor_uber||'\n('||total_valor||')') AS valores,kms,horas_uber,media_hora,media_km " +
                        "FROM uber_records WHERE semana_ano > '"+dias_semana+"' GROUP BY semana_ano ORDER BY dia";
                cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
```

For example, I have 3 records, "a" "b" "c". If I click "back" it goes from "c" to "b" and then clicking again to "a". But if I click "next" being on record "a", it jumps to record "c" and gets data from records "b" and "c"

Comment: are you using `moveToPrevious()` and `moveToNext()` of Cursor class?

Comment: I'm just using moveToFirst() since everything is being done by recording the string retrieved from the data fetched and program SQLite. Move "back" works perfectly but "next" jumps to last record.